# Java 8 stream.map() : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: source already consumed or closed

Tags: java-8, java-stream, illegalstateexception

I have below program which:

1. Reads data from a file as a stream.
2. Create a new stream using stream.map() over the above stream and store it in retVal.
3. Return the retVal.
4. Print the values of Stream retval using forEach, but I get Exception: **IllegalStateException: source already consumed or closed**
5. For function `workingPopulateFromFileAsStream` I have explicitly converted it again to a stream and then it works fine.

Contents of student.txt:

```
Name101,Last101
Name102,Last102
Name103,Last103
Name104,Last104
Name105,Last105
Name106,Last106
Name107,Last107
Name108,Last108
Name109,Last109
Name110,Last110
```

ClientMainApp.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Student {
  String first_name;
  String last_name;

  public Student(String first_name, String last_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return this.first_name + " " + this.last_name;
  }
}

public class ClientMainApp {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    String fileName = "student.txt";
    ClientMainApp obj = new ClientMainApp();

    //Working Code.
    Stream<Student> students_stream = obj.workingPopulateFromFileAsStream(fileName);
    System.out.println("working: Got Student Stream as " + students_stream);
    students_stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("==================================================");

    // Not Working Code.
    Stream<Student> students_stream2 = obj.populateFromFileAsStream2(fileName);
    System.out.println("notWorking: Got Student Stream2 as " + students_stream2);
    students_stream2.forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  private Stream<Student> workingPopulateFromFileAsStream(String fileName) {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
      System.out.println("Working: Got File    Stream as " + stream);
      Stream<Student> retval =
          stream
              .map(
                  st -> {
                    ArrayList<String> record = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(st.split(",")));
                    return new Student(record.get(0), record.get(1));
                  })
              .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream(); // This is the code making the difference.
      System.out.println("Working: Got Retval  Stream as " + retval);
      return retval;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  private Stream<Student> populateFromFileAsStream2(String fileName) {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
      System.out.println("NotWorking: Got File    Stream  as " + stream);
      Stream<Student> retval =
          stream.map(
              st -> {
                ArrayList<String> record = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(st.split(",")));
                return new Student(record.get(0), record.get(1));
              });
      System.out.println("NotWorking: got Retval  Stream  as " + retval);
      return retval;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I get the result as:

```
Working: Got File    Stream as java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@3e3abc88
Working: Got Retval  Stream as java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@214c265e
working: Got Student Stream as java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@214c265e
Name101 Last101
Name102 Last102
Name103 Last103
Name104 Last104
Name105 Last105
Name106 Last106
Name107 Last107
Name108 Last108
Name109 Last109
Name110 Last110
==================================================
NotWorking: Got File    Stream  as java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@7699a589
NotWorking: got Retval  Stream  as java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@4dd8dc3
notWorking: Got Student Stream2 as java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@4dd8dc3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: source already consumed or closed
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.sourceSpliterator(AbstractPipeline.java:406)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at ClientMainApp.main(ClientMainApp.java:38)
```

Here in the response, we can see that the stream object is the same for retVal and that returned back to the calling function, yet I am not sure why it says its already consumed.

Please note that if I use a forEach loop, inside `populateFromFileAsStream2` then it works fine. It's only when the value is returned from the function, it gives an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your non-working version essentially looks like this:

```java
public Stream<String> foo(Path file) throws IOException {
  try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(file)) {
    return stream.map(...);
  }
}
```

You're using a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). That means the `Stream` is closed as soon as the `try` block is exited, which must happen in order for the method to return. Thus you're closing the stream before returning it from the method. That said, I think your mistake is rooted in:

> 2. Create a new stream using stream.map() over the above stream and store it in retVal.

Although it's true that `map` will return a new `Stream` object, the new object is still part of the same conceptual stream/pipeline. In other words, closing the `stream` reference is the same as closing the `retVal` reference. Your working code fixes this problem by returning an entirely new pipeline, though at the cost of buffering the entire file into memory.

Comment: Oh. My bad.
Thanks for solving @Slaw. I already spent 2 days on this and could not identify the issue.
Just missed out try-with-resources aspect. :(